# How to get 2 flags from a make command cobra

Tags: go, go-cobra, viper-go

how do i create a makefile that takes in 2 arguments?
myapp written in go, uses cobra cli. has a command that takes in 2 arguments(flags).

this works

```
$ go build; myapp mycmd --flag1=myvalue1 --flag2=myvalue2
```

in my make file i have

```
//makefile
run:
    @echo Building and Running
    $(GO) build -i -o myapp .
    ./myapp start $(ARGS)
```

so in CLI, when I try

```
$ make run ARGS=--flag1=arg1--flag2=arg2
or
$ make run ARGS=--flag1=arg1,--flag2=arg2
```

doesn't read in the flag values
how do i read in the 2 flag values, it only seems to read in 1 flag value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> make run ARGS=--flag1=arg1--flag2=arg2

Has no separator between the flags

> make run ARGS=--flag1=arg1,--flag2=arg2

Cobra doesn't use ',' as a default flag separator.

Try:
`make run ARGS='--flag1=arg1 --flag2=arg2'`

Tried against a cobra CLI of my own, works perfectly.